# Disable Mouse-wheel to scroll up or down

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I have two pages, these are the conditions I cannot achieve, please let me know if it is not possible.

1. In one page, I need to disable the mouse-wheel to scroll up. So when I scroll up with mouse-wheel nothing happens, but when I scroll down the page scrolls.
2. In the other page, I want the exact opposite, I need to disable the scrolling down on mouse-wheel. So when I scroll down nothing happens, but when I scroll up the page scrolls.

This is all i really need, but if you think I need to explain more, please let me know, thank you.

Comment: Not really, I need to disable separate directions of mouse-wheel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case of preventing mouse scroll down (for mouse scroll up just change comparison operator to '<'):

```
$(window).on("wheel mousewheel", function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    } else if (e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY < 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }    
});
```

We need to check for two values because of cross-browser issues.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/r4ycf1dq/2/)

P. S. Warning. Since later versions of Chrome decides to treat all window events as passive by default, the code above won't work in Chrome. Will come with a better solution and update this answer ASAP.

Comment: Sorry, been awhile since i used this code. Corrected myself. Also, added a fiddle.

Comment: Just tested your fiddle in Chrome and it seems to no longer work.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately Chrome made all window events passive by default, which means they can't be prevented. I will come up with a better solution, and will leave a warning for a time being.

Comment: Wraping all elements in a `<div id='foo'>` and using `$('#foo').on('wheel', ...)` will work. In this way you may even specify which parts are not scrollable.

Answer (score 10):

This code works for div with id "mydiv".  You can change the mydiv to the body or any other element you want. The code works in all browsers.

**JS:**

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
if (mydiv.addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    mydiv.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
    // Firefox
    mydiv.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
}
// IE 6/7/8
else 
    mydiv.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);


function MouseWheelHandler(e) {

    // cross-browser wheel delta
    var e = window.event || e; // old IE support
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

    if(delta==1)         // if mouse scrolls up
    {
         alert('up');  
    }
    if(delta==-1)        // if mouse scrolls down, we disable scrolling.
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**NOTE**: Remember to set overflow to auto or scroll for this function to work.

A working example: [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jjesuraj/8bgfhq4x/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is working but some edits are needed (1) **var** e = window.event || e;  // if you use "var" you rewrite the variable that is used in the argument  (2) you need to compare with strict comparison the delta value (like delta=== 1)

Answer (score -3):

You could try this to disable mouse scroll. I understand this is not as per your question but I believe it could help you.

**JS:**

```
function disableMouseScroll() {
    return false;
}
document.onmousewheel=disableMouseScroll;
```

[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent)

Comment: @TheLittlePig Thanks Man but just for your information, recently I had done this disabling mouse scroll. So I thought to put my answer as much as I know and I posted it. I believe its not about copy paste thing, its about helping others in any way.